# Mixing Android Views and GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm currently working on a game and I would hate to get halfway through and find that the what I'm doing causes errors/kills performance. This is how I'm thinking of setting it up.

[image: Layout of Views]

First want to have a LinearLayout with a LinearLayout containing a HUD, and then a GLSurfaceView. However I may at certain points "pause" the game view and switch to a different linear layout containing an inventory or equips, etc.

I think this way would be best because I can make use of all the great components that android comes with rather than making my own with OpenGL. However I am worried that mixing the two types of view may have some problems. Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I've been using a FrameLayout with the GLSurfaceView as the first element. I.e. at the bottom of the stack, with other views / viewgroups layered over the top of it. I'd recommend just pausing the game-loop and placing some opaque view over the top of it to hide it rather than swapping views in and out or whatever:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/graphics_frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/graphics_glsurfaceview1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/inventory" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/HUD" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Android Framelayout for games. Check out ma ms paint skillz]