# Android: How do I resize the GLSurfaceView so I can add buttons around the outside?

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, colors, glsurfaceview

I have a 3d model viewer, but I want to modify it, so hear are some questions/issues:

***(OpenGL ES 2.0)***

**1.** Is it possible to change the GLSurfaceView dimensions (height and width) to something like 600 x 800 and centered on the device (tablet) screen? I want to use the unused area to line buttons around the outside.

**2.** Is it possible to resize glSurfaceView in XML?

**3.** Is there a way to set an XML layout on top of the screen?

**4.** Is it possible to set a background color under the rendering so that it's not all black?

*For reference as to what I'm trying to achieve, search "STL Viewer" on the android market.*

Comment: Based on rather short experimenting on GLSurfaceView via layouts I came to conclusion it isn't necessary the best way to try adding padding/border/centering etc attributes for it. Instead it may be better to let GLSurfaceView occupy whole view area and add other views on top of it using FrameLayout (for example). Within GLSurfaceView.Renderer you can then handle borders and centering by using different viewport than (0, 0, width, height).

Comment: Thanx harism. I'm using the example of a model viewer from this site: http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/03/13/shaders-android/

Comment: @harism: From what you said, how do I apply other views? I pretty much just need buttons in the foreground, then the GLSurfaceView under it. How do I apply the FrameLayout to sit on top from the example I'm using from the website?

Comment: You can put GLSurfaceView in your XML layout and then just get it using `findViewById` like you might for any other. Check my answer here for an example (with picture!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128896/mixing-android-views-and-glsurfaceview/8231526#8231526