# rendering Views components over GLSurfaseView

Tags: java, android, glsurfaceview

I want to put some views on top of GL surface, finally I came up with solution with structure:

[image]

I have such layouts structure with root layout - FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent>

    <GLSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    // here I put all my views which I want to be on top of GL surface

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

It works fine on my Samsung galaxy s3 and emulators (from android SDK and Genymotion). 
But it fails on Xperia, for some reason on this device all graphics objects on GLSurfaceView are not displayed.

Could you please give me advice - is my approach is correct and what can cause the issue on some devices?

Is there any other more correct way to display Views from android sdk on top of GLSurfaceView?

Comment: GLSurfaceView doesn't work too well with padding and/or margins on all devices. See first comment on this question for workaround ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772783/android-how-do-i-resize-the-glsurfaceview-so-i-can-add-buttons-around-the-outsi .

Comment: what is the resolution of image you are trying to draw?

Comment: I'm trying to draw gl objects (including textures, polylines etc) and after that I want to draw Views (Buttons, etc) on top of this gl surface. So it's not about drawing of some image in general

Comment: @harism So is it possible that GLSurfaceView might not draw gl graphics  at all if there are margins/paddings in XML config for GLSurfaceView?

Comment: @XZen ah, my bad. No. I never faced such an issue nothing was rendered at all. Sorry for not reading the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: The GLSurfaceView surface is a completely independent layer, composited by the system, not the app.  It will either appear above or below all Views, and cannot be sandwiched between them.  There are three possible Z-orderings relative to the View layer, two below and one above.  [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)'s "multi-surface test" demonstrates multiple overlapping transparent SurfaceView surfaces, sharing the screen with Views.

By default, the surface appears behind the View, which appears to be what you want.  If you're not seeing the GLSurfaceView surface, it's probably because the View on top of it has an opaque background.  My guess is that the default UI theme is different between your different devices, and one is providing transparency while another isn't.

On API 14+, the framework provides a way to intermix Views and surfaces, using [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).  Using GLES with a TextureView isn't much harder than GLSurfaceView -- you just have to do your own EGL setup.  Grafika's GLES library demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems in case of moving to TextureView I have to implement 'queueEvent' method as well.

Comment: Well, I need to take a look at the documentation, it's just not pretty clear to me where is all the 'magic' related to GLThread which contains in GLSurfaceView class :)

Comment: GLSurfaceView and its associated classes are just helpers built on top of SurfaceView.  All of that should really be moved to a "support" library; it doesn't need to be part of the core framework.  All you really need is to set up EGL to render to a Surface and then start drawing on your thread of choice.

Comment: Thank you for clarification :) These helpers are quite convenient when you don't like to do all the stuff related to rendering thread lifecycle and EGL setup manually. It seems I have no choice and should implement this logic, just as it is done in GLSurfaceView.

Comment: Grafika's OpenGL ES subroutines (https://github.com/google/grafika/tree/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles) take care of the EGL stuff.  You do have to deal with the threading, which can be a bit complicated (https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).  In any event, if you're okay with the surface being Z-ordered below all of the View elements, you may be able to solve the original problem with an explicit theme selection.

Comment: Explicit theme selection sounds easier, but as I understand it's a bad practice since it's unexpected behavior from the user's point of view. From the other point of view dealing with the threading might take more time and it might be less reliably, threading is always not trivial for me. Thank you, basically I understood the idea :)

Comment: I've just managed to replace SurefaceView by TextureView with the same structure of layouts as in the question, but unfortunately I've got the same issue! It works on my Samsung S3 and fails on Xperia.. I set theme in my android manifest for activity and application. Please give any advise why this may happen.. :C