# Moving background, stationary image in front, using view

Tags: android, background

I want to have a view (not using surfaceview) background that is a moving road/trees background with a stationary vehicle in the front (well the vehicle image will be stationary  but with the impression it is moving). What is the most elegant method of scrolling the background tile repeatedly?

PS user will not interact with it although I will need to change the image in front

Comment: Have you checked JetBoy application? It has very simple and easy to understand example on how to make "parallax" scrolling.

Comment: I don't want to do a full screen surfaceview or have user interaction. I am going with https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo at this time as the most promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An endlessly scrolling scrollview was the answer, with the background cut up into into at least 2 pieces. For the vehicle driving in front I used frameviews as per [Mixing Android Views and GLSurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128896/mixing-android-views-and-glsurfaceview).

PS The relatively undocumented sample code, at https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo gave me most of what I wanted for the scrollview.